# Expo commands throwing "Error: Cannot find module 'minizlib'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm, expo

Whenever I try to run such commands as `expo init` or `expo start` or even just `expo`, it responds with:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'minizlib'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/tar/lib/pack.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/tar/lib/create.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/tar/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/Extract.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/Api.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/xdl.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/build/exp.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/tar/lib/pack.js:28:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:19)
```

I have tried install and reinstalling minizlib, along with expo, expo-cli, npm, and node and nothing has worked.
Any help would be appreciated.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2

Comment: `brew install node`
`brew install watchman`

Comment: @hongdevelop was this supposed to fix expo or to serve as a replacement for expo?

Comment: These are what you need to use an expo.

Comment: @hongdevelop it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I downgraded to version 10 of node using `nvm install 10` (If you do not have NVM look into it [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) it is very useful) then reinstalled the expo-cli with `npm install -g expo-cli`. This ended up solving the issue for me.

**Note:** This downgrade is temporary if you want to make it your default version you have to run `nvm alias default 10`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with "minizlib" not being found. None of the solutions posted on here or other threads regarding this issue solved it.

**But, I figured it out. And here is what worked for me. Its pretty straight forward.**

- All the modules necessary for Expo to run should be located at
  `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/`
- So, go to your home directory and run `npm install minizlib@2.1.0`.
  This will put the module file in the home directory. (I say home
  directory so that the npm install doesnt clutter files into whichever
  directory you were previously working on)
- Now, you need to copy+paste the module folder to whichever folder npm
  is looking for while running the expo command. In your case its
  `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/`

This solved the problem for me. If it worked for anyone else, please validate it for me.

Answer (score 1):

install the library

```
npm install -g minizlib
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found the way to solve it in an [external forum.](https://forums.expo.io/t/expo-isnt-working/25293/8) thanks to  @parkerroanm answer there.

Anyway, here is how I solved it (from the answer I found):

1. I uninstalled expo-cli with this command: `sudo npm uninstall -g expo-cli` This is did not actually uninstall expo and nothing I could do would. So i deleted the folder with this command: sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli
2. Then reinstalled using yarn instead with: `yarn global add expo-cli --save`
3. I updated the `PATH` in `.bashrc` to include `export PATH="$(yarn global bin):$PATH"` to the bottom of the file.

This fixed the issue for me.

> It seems to all stem from a permissions error on installation for the
>   sharp library.

Comment: Thanks for improving my answer. I am brazilian and i am still learning english ..