# react native expo Cannot find module 'minizlib'

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo

Following the read.me at https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app

After I select my template with the `expo init` command, I got this error

```
Cannot find module 'minizlib'
Error: Cannot find module 'minizlib'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/tar/lib/pack.js:28:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/tar/lib/create.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
```

I already tried everything that are on these thread :

[Expo commands throwing "Error: Cannot find module 'minizlib'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56998174/expo-commands-throwing-error-cannot-find-module-minizlib)

[Cannot find module 'minizlib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495253/cannot-find-module-minizlib)

*So I already uninstalled/install Nodejs, try to install it with brew, and tried to install minizlib, it doesn't change anything.*

Nodejs version : v10.16.3

Os : Pop!_OS 18.04 LTS

If anyone can help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

So finally I try to mess with nvm and test every node version to see if it works.

```
nvm install <number of node version>
npm install -g expo-cli
```

It finally works with `nvm install 10`, (still I don't know why I needed to do that as I already have nodeJs 10)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with "minizlib" not being found. None of the solutions posted on here or other threads regarding this issue solved it.

**I figured out the solution and posted it on the most recent thread on this issue.** [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56998174/expo-commands-throwing-error-cannot-find-module-minizlib/58290209#58290209)